# (Selenium ruby) How to add debuggerAddress experimental option?

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

### Discription

I want to attach selenium to existing session of chrome, and then tweak pages using my chrome profile, but from terminal
I have found that this is [feasible using debuggerAddress](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=710#c3)

### Excerpt -

```
Launch Chrome from command prompt:
chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=8181

Sample Code:
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.setExperimentalOption("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:8181");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("test");
        driver.quit();
```

### Steps to reproduce -

```
// close all chrome windows
$ google-chrome-stable --remote-debugging-port=4444
// chrome opened with my profile
$ pry
>  require 'selenium-webdriver'
>  Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.path = '/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable'
>  Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.driver_path = '/usr/bin/chromedriver'
>  options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
>  # options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:4444") # how????
>  driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, options: options
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ruby client doesn't have `add_experimental_option`.

Use `add_option` instead:

```
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
options.add_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:4444")
```