# Selenium Webdriver - set preferred browser language DE

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a problem setting the preferred (accepted language) within headless Chrome using Selenium Webdriver and Ruby. I use the following WebDriver settings:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.driver_path = @config[<path to the Chrome Driver>]

options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-translate')
options.add_argument("--lang=de")
```

The driver is then initialized with:

```
@selenium_driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, options: options
```

Everything works fine but aont some pages, Chrome returns English content even when I navigate to the German page URL (e.g. page.de). In these cases, the Chrome driver returns the English content due to an internal forwarding to page.de/en. I do not specify the en path in my queried URL.

I have tried to set the language using the Webdriver preference:

```
options.add_preference('accept_languages', 'de')
```

instead of the add_argument but it doesn't change anything of the behavior.

Does anyone have an idea how to force a headless Chrome controlled by Selenium Webdriver within Ruby to request page content in a defined language or - not optimal but it might help as a workaround - to stop the forwarding?

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution that works for me. As in many cases the problem was sitting in front of the screen and simply doesn't work precisely enough ;-)

Instead of using

```
options.add_argument("--lang=de")
```

you have to use

```
options.add_argument("--lang=de-DE")
```

When I use an IETF language tag the code I initially posted works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I'am using this in my `test_helper.rb` Works fine for me.

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Chromedriver.set_version "2.36"

  desired_capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
    'chromeOptions' => {
      'prefs' => {
        'intl.accept_languages' => 'en-US'
     },
     args: ['disable-gpu', 'headless']
   }
  )

  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, { browser: :chrome, desired_capabilities: desired_capabilities })
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :chrome
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
```

Comment: Hello Chris, many thanks for your quick response. That could be a general approach. Unfortunately in my specific situation I cannot use Capybara and have to stick to the plain Selenium WebDriver + the Chrome driver. Krid

Answer (score 1):

This `prefs` hash inside an `options` hash did the trick for me. It's at the end of the `driven_by :selenium` line.

(Inside `test/application_syste_test_case.rb`)

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'test_helper'
require 'capybara/rails'

class ApplicationSystemTestCase < ActionDispatch::SystemTestCase
  driven_by :selenium, using: :chrome, screen_size: [1400, 1400], options: { prefs: { 'intl.accept_languages' => 'de,de-DE;q=0.9,en;q=0.1' } }

# ...
```

##### 2021-06-14 UPDATE:

The previous example produces this deprecation warning:

`WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION] :prefs is deprecated. Use Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options#add_preference instead.`

IMO, the solution below is uglier, but I'm posting it for when it's fully deprecated and the original stops working.

```rb
class ApplicationSystemTestCase < ActionDispatch::SystemTestCase
  driven_by(:selenium,
    using: :chrome,
    screen_size: [1400, 1400],
    options: {
      options: Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new(
        prefs: { 'intl.accept_languages' => 'de,de-DE;q=0.9,en;q=0.1' }
      )
    },
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to solve your problem by adding an *experimental option*:

```
options.add_option('prefs', {'intl.accept_languages': 'en,en_US'})
```

I'm sure it works with Python, but I've not tried with Ruby: this approach is the correct one, not sure about the implementation.
You can find in [this repository](https://gist.github.com/BuhtigithuB/11df8cf8d03bb236985156de204fe7b4) the code which handles your problem in Python code, and in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45400113/selenium-ruby-how-to-add-debuggeraddress-experimental-option) how to implement experimental_options in Ruby

Comment: Hello Gsk, thanks for your answer as well. Unfortunately I'm not able to find the Ruby expression that works. Tried different combinations of the proposed arguments but nothing changed the behavior. e.g. options.add_preference('intl.accept_languages','de'). The web doesn't provide anything beyond that as well. Either there is not way to tell Chrome with Selenium Webdriver to use another language than EN or it is very well hidden. Krid

Comment: according to the docs there is a method `add_preference` could you try `options .add_preference('intl.accept_languages', 'de')`

Answer (score 0):

For me works:

```
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Options.new
options.add_preference("intl.accept_languages", 'de-DE')
Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :firefox, options: options)
```

Answer (score 0):

```rb
chrome_options.add_argument("--lang=en")
 
chrome_options.add_argument("--enable-experimental-accessibility-language-detection-dynamic")

chrome_options.add_argument("--enable-experimental-accessibility-language-detection")
```

This should help to set language to English for chrome headless mode

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).